# Removing active class from element when hovering on another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `<ul>` with seven `<li>` items in it. The first one will have a class `active` on pageload and I want to remove it once one of the another elements are hovered, as well as add the `active` class to the hovered element and keep the last hovered element active even if the mouse leaves the element. I have the following jQuery and it works, except it also removes the active class from the first active element as it toggles it and removes the class, that is only on the first hover, and the active class disappears if the mouse leaves the element. Thanks!

```js
$(".solutions-items li").hover(function() {
  return $(this).toggleClass("solutions-items-active").siblings().removeClass("solutions-items-active");
});
```

```html
<ul class="solutions-items">
  <li class="solutions-items-active">1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/0c1sanpn/1/

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get back active class to original link after leaving others links:

**[Updated]** (*as `hover` is deprecated*)

```js
$('nav ul li')
  .on('mouseenter', function () {
    $('nav ul li.active').removeClass('active');    // remove class from previous active item
    $(this).addClass('active');                     // item class to the current one
  })
  .on('mouseleave', function () {
    $('nav ul li.active').removeClass('active');    // remove class from previous active item
    active.addClass('active');                      // item class to the current one
  });
```

---

*OLD:*

```js
var active = $('.active');
$('nav ul li').hover(
  function () {
    $('nav ul li.active').removeClass('active'); // remove class from previous active item
    $(this).addClass('active');                  // item class to the current one
  },
  function () {
    $('nav ul li.active').removeClass('active'); // remove class from previous active item
    active.addClass('active');                   // item class to the current one
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

First remove the `solutions-items-active` class from all list items, with the selector `$('.solutions-items li')`. Then add the active class to the one that is hovered.

```js
$(".solutions-items li").hover(function() {
  $('.solutions-items li').removeClass('solutions-items-active');
  $(this).addClass('solutions-items-active');
});
```

```css
.solutions-items-active { color: red /* just for the demo */ }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="solutions-items">
  <li class="solutions-items-active">1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. Use mouseenter instead of hover

```
 $(".solutions-items li").mouseenter(function() {
  return $(this).toggleClass("solutions-items-active").siblings().removeClass("solutions-items-active");
});
```

JS Fidle : http://jsfiddle.net/0c1sanpn/

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simply, `removeClass` & `addClass`

```
$('.solutions-items li').hover(function() {
    $('.solutions-items-active').removeClass('solutions-items-active'); // remove class from previous active item
    $(this).addClass('solutions-items-active'); // item class to the current one
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Ldovtjyn/